# How to pin a window on top of other windows in OS X?

Tags: macos, window-manager, spaces

I used to use an app called [Afloat](http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/master-windows-afloat-mac) that let me pin windows on top of all other windows on the Desktop. However, Afloat stopped being maintained at some point and it doesn't work with more recent versions of OS X.

I then used an app called [Compulsion](http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/01/31/always-on-top-in-macos-yosemite/), which installed as a SIMBL plugin but then that stopped working with OS X El Capitan.

Is there a way to get either of these apps to work with OS X El Capitan? Or is there another solution I can try?

Comment: The top of the link you shared to Compulsion mentions it works in OS X El Capitan. Is this misinformation?

Answer (score 12):

Try using Helium.  It uses a 'customizable translucency' to keep a window on top of other windows.  Plus, it won't intercept mouse clicks on top of it unless you want it to.

As of now, it only supports a browser window but the question doesn't indicate if that's a requirement of the OP or not.

EDIT Feb 2022: Original link is dead.  I'm linking to the [author's GitHub page here](https://github.com/JadenGeller/Helium) for Helium can't determine if the project is still being updated.

Comment: This is great if all you want to do is browse the web. Otherwise, not so much.

Comment: @LukeTaylor which is exactly what I indicated in my answer so I don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: Great, now one that lets the terminal float too.... I miss this feature moving from kde!

Comment: Site is "Available for sale"

Comment: Could you please update your answer. The link is not working anymore.

Comment: @VarunW. Thanks, I've updated the link to the author's github but don't know if this still works or not.  Also, anyone can update an answer if they have enough reputation on the site.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest trying kwm https://github.com/koekeishiya/kwm

From my experience, the whole intention of having one window always on top is to read/compare/reference to it while working on another app.

"Tiled window manger" solutions works much better for this purpose. After having tried `Athethyst` https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst, I came to `kwm`. I find `kwm` offers a better way of configuration. It relies on a config file. After installation, which takes a bit more work then Amethyst, and reading through the sample config file, you already feel yourself a poweruser already. So It's worth to try.

A note though, when I start doing advanced fancy configuration, `kwm` starts having quite some hiccups.

Edit: `kwm` is now called `yabai` https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai

Comment: I used to use this all the time with KDE, it's useful for everything. Comparing documents, but also watching a movie on top, having  a terminal always handy, or your file manager.

Comment: `kwm` is no longer available, the link is broken.